# How to hide private overloaded function from visual studio IntelliSence hint?

Tags: c++, intellisense

I have this class:

```
class BST
{
public:
   void insert(int val) { insert(node, val); }
private:
   void insert(std::shared_ptr<Node> node, int i);
   std::shared_ptr<Node> node = nullptr;
};
```

Here I have public function ***insert*** for class users. And private overloaded version of if.
And when I want to call this function from driver code, in IntelliSence hint I have two overloads of this function.
[image]

So if there is a way to hide private function from user?

Comment: There is no way.  The access control happens after the overload resolution. A compiler works in a such way. IntelliSense behaves similarly.

Comment: Perhaps give it a different name, like `insert_shared`?

Comment: It would be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9027338/how-to-hide-private-members-of-a-class, but that is 11 years old, smth might be changed since that time.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the macro `__INTELLISENSE__` to hide class members from IntelliSense suggestions.

```
class BST {
 public:
  void insert(int val) { insert(node, val); }

 private:
#ifndef __INTELLISENSE__ 
  void insert(std::shared_ptr<Node> node, int i);
#endif

  std::shared_ptr<Node> node = nullptr;
};
```

The tip is giving here: [Troubleshooting Tips for IntelliSense Slowness](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/troubleshooting-tips-for-intellisense-slowness/).

Unfortunately, this is not a good enough solution. It will hide suggestions even in the correct access scopes, in own class methods.

Comment: Oooh, how nifty

Comment: the code seems to work, but now visual studio complains that the overloaded version of the function does not exist, when I use it in class :)

Comment: As always, this a world of trade-offs, better suggestions, but worse error highlights on the fly, or wise versa.

Comment: I like @Bop's suggestion.  Why do you need to use the same name for two different functions here, that's what's causing you all this grief?